# Xamrin.Forms trying to create Email check using Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I'm new to using Xamarin.Forms, I'm currently working on creating a sign up page. I'm trying to create some way to check if an email is already been used when creating an account. I am using firebase realtime database. I manage to get the application to check if the email has been used and display an error, but when the email is valid(not used), when I go to create the account the application doesn't do anything. What am I missing?

I have provided the code

```
    public Command SignUpCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(() =>
            {
                var hasSymbols = new Regex(@"[!@#$%^&*()_+=\[{\]};:<>|./?,-]");

                //null or empty field validation, check weather email and password is null or empty
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Email) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password))
                {
                    App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Empty Values", "Please enter Email and Password", "OK");
                }
                else if (!Email.Contains("@"))
                {
                    App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("", "Email Address is Invalid", "OK");
                }
                else if (Password.Length < 8)
                {
                    App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("", "Password is less than 8 characters", "OK");
                }
                else if (!Password.Any(char.IsUpper))
                {
                    App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("", "Password Must Contain at Least 1 Uppcase Letter", "OK");
                }
                else if (!hasSymbols.IsMatch(Password))
                {
                    App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("", "Password should contain At least one special case characters", "OK");
                }
                else if (Password != ConfirmPassword)
                {
                    App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("", "Password must be same as above!", "OK");
                }
                else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(StudentID))
                {
                    App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Empty Values", "Please enter Student ID", "OK");
                }
                else if (StudentID.Length < 9)
                {
                    App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("", "Student ID is Incorrect!", "OK");
                }
                else
                {
                    EmailCheck();
                }

            });

        }

    }

    private async void EmailCheck()
    {

        //call GetUser function which we define in Firebase helper class
        var user = await FirebaseHelper.GetUser(Email);
        //firebase return null valuse if user data not found in database
        if (user != null)
            if (Email == user.Email)
            {
                await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Email Already Used", "", "Ok");
            }
            else
                SignUp();
    }

    private async void SignUp()
    {
        //call AddUser function which we define in Firebase helper class
        var user = await FirebaseHelper.AddUser(Email, Password, StudentID, FirstName, LastName, CarMake, CarModel,
                                                CarYear, CarColor, LicenseNumber);
        //AddUser return true if data insert successfuly 
        if (user)
        {
            await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("SignUp Success", "", "Ok");
            //Navigate to Wellcom page after successfuly SignUp
            //pass user email to welcom page
            await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new LoginPage());
        }
        else
            await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", "SignUp Fail", "OK");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by the Application does not do anything? I am not sure this is related to the issue you are having but I would definitely await SignUp(); within EmailCheck()

Comment: by application i mean when i build the project and run the emulator. When I'm on the sign up page and click the sign up button, the button doesn't do anything, but if i go from the command SignUpCommand() straight to the signup(), bypassing the EmailCheck() the account does get created and takes me to the login page.

Comment: also when i add await to SignUp() i get an error saying i cannot await a void, but if i remove the void from the SignUp() i get another error.

Comment: True, you can not await a void return type change it from void to Task and you will be able to await this method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, you want to create project, Register account using Email account, and sign up to navigate another content page.

But I find your code is a bit messy, I do one simple sample that you can take a look:

```
 <StackLayout>
    <!--  Place new controls here  -->
    <Entry x:Name="txtemail" Placeholder="Email" />
    <Entry x:Name="txtpassword" Placeholder="Enter Password" />
    <Entry x:Name="txtstudentId" Placeholder="Enter Student Id" />
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button
            x:Name="btnSign"
            Clicked="BtnSign_Clicked"
            Text="Sign up"
            WidthRequest="200" />
        <Button
            x:Name="btnRegister"
            Clicked="BtnRegister_Clicked"
            Text="Retrive"
            WidthRequest="200" />
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>

 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    FirebaseHelper firebaseHelper = new FirebaseHelper();
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void BtnSign_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var person = await firebaseHelper.GetPerson(txtemail.Text);
        if (person != null)
        {
            if(person.Email==txtpassword.Text)
            {
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1());
            }
            else
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Fail", "Password is not correct!", "OK");
            }              
        }
        else
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Fail", "No email Available!", "OK");
        }
    }

    private async void BtnRegister_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(await RegisterAccount())
        {
            await firebaseHelper.AddPerson(txtemail.Text, txtpassword.Text, txtstudentId.Text);
            txtemail.Text = string.Empty;
            txtpassword.Text = string.Empty;
            txtstudentId.Text = string.Empty;
            await DisplayAlert("Success", "Person Added Successfully", "OK");
        }
        else
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Fail", "Person Added Fail", "OK");
        }


    }

    private async Task<bool> RegisterAccount()
    {
        var hasSymbols = new Regex(@"[!@#$%^&*()_+=\[{\]};:<>|./?,-]");

        //null or empty field validation, check weather email and password is null or empty
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtemail.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtpassword.Text))
        {
          await  DisplayAlert("Empty Values", "Please enter Email and Password", "OK");

            return false;
        }
        else if (!txtemail.Text.Contains("@"))
        {
            await DisplayAlert("", "Email Address is Invalid", "OK");
            return false;
        }
        else if (txtpassword.Text.Length < 8)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("", "Password is less than 8 characters", "OK");
            return false;
        }
        else if (!txtpassword.Text.Any(char.IsUpper))
        {
            await DisplayAlert("", "Password Must Contain at Least 1 Uppcase Letter", "OK");
            return false;
        }
        else if (!hasSymbols.IsMatch(txtpassword.Text))
        {
            await DisplayAlert("", "Password should contain At least one special case characters", "OK");
            return false;
        }

        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtstudentId.Text))
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Empty Values", "Please enter Student ID", "OK");
            return false;
        }

        else
        {
            var person = await firebaseHelper.GetPerson(txtemail.Text);
            if (person != null)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("fail", "Email already exist", "OK");
                return false;

            }
        }

        return true;

    }
}

public class Register
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string StudentId { get; set; }
}

 public class FirebaseHelper
{
    FirebaseClient firebase = new FirebaseClient("https://testapp1-ebb27-6e5ba.firebaseio.com/");

    public async Task<List<Register>> GetAllPersons()
    {

        return (await firebase
          .Child("Persons")
          .OnceAsync<Register>()).Select(item => new Register
          {
              Email = item.Object.Email,
              Password = item.Object.Password,
              StudentId=item.Object.StudentId

          }).ToList();
    }

    public async Task AddPerson(string email, string password, string studentid)
    {

        await firebase
          .Child("Persons")
          .PostAsync(new Register() { Email = email, Password = password, StudentId = studentid });

    }

    public async Task<Register> GetPerson(string email)
    {
        var allPersons = await GetAllPersons();
        await firebase
          .Child("Persons")
          .OnceAsync<Register>();
        return allPersons.Where(a => a.Email == email).FirstOrDefault();
    }


}
```

This is my sample at github:

https://github.com/CherryBu/RegisterApp

[image]